# Converting Spring ParameterizedTypeReference to Jackson TypeReference

Tags: spring, jackson

I am using spring RestTemplate in a library. Input of the library method accepting a `ParameterizedTypeRecerence` and passing it to rest template for conversion.

For reasons unrelated, I need to get the response body as byte[] and convert if manually to json using Jackson.
Jackson expects a `TypeReference` class to do the conversion.

I am looking for a way to convert these to classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can use helper class

```
public class CustomTypeReference extends TypeReference<Object>{
    private final Type type;

    public CustomTypeReference(ParameterizedTypeReference pt){
        this.type = pt.getType();
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> typeRef
        = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
TypeReference tr = new CustomTypeReference(typeRef);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = "[\"key\", \"someStr\"]";
List<String> data = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, tr);
```

---

Or just anonymous `TypeReference<Object>`

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> typeRef
        = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};

TypeReference tr = new TypeReference<Object>(){
    public Type getType() {
        return typeRef.getType();
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean `TypeReference<List<String>> tr = new CustomTypeReference(typeRef);`

Comment: @Arash nope, `TypeReference tr = new CustomTypeReference(typeRef);` or TypeReference<Object>, but it doesn't matter, because `CustomTypeReference` ignores generic declaration and doesn't rely on it in any way and uses the type you passed in constructor. The `TypeReference<T>` is actually abstract class and you just need to override `getType()` to make it work the way you want it to.  Just ignore https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java#L33-L44 default _type variable.